# codename one Resize Image quality

Tags: codenameone

My requirement is to show the small image into the bigger one at the same quality. I have tried setting the background image to the container, scaleImageLabel, ImageViewer by doing so I can achieve the required size but the quality is not good.

using cloudinary is the only option to go with or if there is any other option available.
Following code has been used.

```
    ImageViewer iv = new ImageViewer();   
    iv.setImageInitialPosition(IMAGE_FIT);
    iv.setPreferredH(Display.getInstance().getDisplayHeight() / 2);
    iv.setImageNoReposition(vi.img);
```

[image] 
Need to remove the blank space top and bottom

while using IMAGE_FILL image has been croped

[image]

Comment: You say what you used but you don't give any code examples, image dimensions, screenshots or any other information. Scaling inherently impacts quality but thumbnails work just fine when done right without Cloudinary (although they are a fine option).

Comment: now i have updated the question with  code..

Comment: Image viewer is designed for dynamic scaling, is that what you actually need? You can scale an image with the `ImageIO` API for a smaller size and keep the original high resolution image in a different file